# symfony form generate not expected placeholder element

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, formbuilder

usually there should be two outputs both filles with taxonomy ids - somehow there is a "placeholder" element which causes errors. i dont really understand were it comes from, any ideas? i tought the best idea is to show it within a screenshot (and additional, a part of it as code). the output is with twig's dump() function.

generated symfony form element id's within dump() (3 form elements, 2 expected):

```
"id" => "Filter_filter_1462_boolcollectionradiomodell_placeholder"
"id" => "Filter_filter_1462_boolcollectionradiomodell_8368"
"id" => "Filter_filter_1462_boolcollectionradiomodell_33696"
```

here the screenshots with the ids and some additional information like the empty value from the symfony form element:
[image]

the value is empty, the other ones (the expected ones) are filled with taxonomy ids.

here is the symfony form part:

```
$builder->add(
    'filter_' . $filter->getId() . '_boolcollectionradio',
    EntityType::class,
    array(
        'class' => AutoTaxonomie::class,
        'choices' => $choices,
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false,
        'required' => false,
        'label' => ('detail' == $this->entry) ? $tmp : false,
        'attr' => array('data-taxid' => $filter->getId(), 'class' => 'form-group'),
        'choice_label' => function (AutoTaxonomie $taxonomie) {
            $view_data = array(
                'title' => $taxonomie->getTitle(),
                'beschreibung' => $taxonomie->getDescription(),
            );

            return json_encode($view_data);
        },
    )
);
```

symfony: 3.4
twig: 2.5

any advice is highly appreciated, have a nice one!

Comment: I advice you to avoid posting textual output as image, some will downvote your question because of that.

Comment: i understand but if i post the 3 arrays as code its also against the stackoverflow rules because the main part of my question would be code. probably i should show off just the generated id from the form element, there you can see the _placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying a placeholder element for the `EntityTypeField` is the default, as [documented](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/entity.html#placeholder).
Try setting it to false to prevent it from appearing:

```
$builder->add('filter_', EntityType::class, array(
    'placeholder' => false,
));
```